What’s the oldest surviving telenovela?
I know Sua Vida Me Pertence (1951, Brazil) and Senda prohibida (1958, Mexico) are the first telenovelas but unfortunately they're completely lost with photos being the only existing visual evidence of them, so I'm wondering what's the oldest surviving telenovela still available to watch?

Does it have to be latin-american or not (telenovela only or soap opera too)? Does it have to be "visual" or can it be (like soaps), radiophonic?

It has to be latin-american, since the word “telenovelas” always refers to soap operas made in the Central and South America. And they has to be both visual and radiophonic.

As far back in time as I can remember (and if this fits your criteria), there's a Marx Bros. radio show that aired in 1932. At that time, there was no definition of soap opera or sitcom, even though, nowadays, the MB show would probably be a sitcom...

…..yeah no, it doesn’t really fit my criteria. It’s a comedy show, not a soap lol
